# Taking a string input from user by a dynamically allocated structure variable

Tags: c, string, dynamic, input, structure

My name variable is a fixed variable which is inside a structure student.

When I run my code, the input part skips the name, or as a matter of fact, in whichever character variable I put a space, the next character input is skipped. The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student{
char name[50];
char roll[10];
char batch[20];
long int mob;
};
 struct student *stud;
int main()
{
int num,i;
printf("Enter the number of students in the class: ");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("Enter the following records: ");
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("student.txt", "w");
for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    stud = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student)*num);
    printf("\nStudent %d: ",i+1);

    printf("\nEnter Name: ");

    scanf("%s",stud->name);

    printf("\nEnter Roll No.: ");
    scanf("%s",stud->roll);
    printf("\nEnter Batch: ");
    scanf("%s",stud->batch);
    printf("Enter mobile number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&stud->mob);
    fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %ld",stud->name,stud->roll,stud->batch,stud->mob);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` stops reading characters once it encounter a whitespace. Better to use `fgets`.

```
fgets(stud->name, 50, stdin);
```

Note that `fgets` also read `'\n'` character if the input characters are fewer than that of array size. You need to take care of that.

Comment: Hi! You say that fgets will also read '\n', so instead of fgets, i tried using gets(stud->name), since I dont know the length of the user name input. But it is still not taking the input.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to use `scanf` correctly.
One issue is that many of the specifiers will eat leading white space (for example `%d`) but some do not (for example `%s`).

In your case:

```
  scanf("%d",&num);              /* eats any white space BEFORE the number */
                                 /* but leaves the newline from pressing */
                                 /* enter sitting in the input buffer */
```

...then...

```
scanf("%s",stud->name);          /* because %s does NOT skip leading */
                                 /* white space, stops at the newline */
```

an improvement is:

```
scanf(" %.49s",stud->name);      /* skip WS, ensure no overflow */
```